# How to delete the whole line in batch file and retranslate it to the output file?

Tags: parsing, batch-file, cmd

As I am new here, I have some problems "coding" in batch file.

I have an input-output file `file.txt` with some data (Name Surname Sex Age) and also have some functions that should be made with this file, e.g.:

- add a person,
- delete a person,
- sort people,
- exit,
- show the list

The main problem happens when I choose the function to delete a person. I have tried to overwrite the file with `type %~f1 | findstr /v %name% > %~f1`, but it deletes everything from the input-output file. I have also tried `type %~f1 | findstr /v %name% >> %~f1`, but it adds some lines that I do not need...

I need a function that would delete the whole line, which contains the entered name (or surname) and would show me the output file without that line.

```
@echo off

:PAT
cls
color 4f

echo.
if exist %~f1 (
    rem goto PRA
) else (
    echo ERROR
    goto END
)

:PRA
echo Menu:
echo 1) Add a person
echo 2) Delete a person
echo 3) Sort
echo 4) Exit
echo 5) Show the list

echo.
choice /c 12345 /m "Choice: "


if errorlevel 5 goto AAA
if errorlevel 4 goto END
if errorlevel 3 goto SOR
if errorlevel 2 goto DEL
if errorlevel 1 goto ADD

:EOF
pause

:END
choice /m "Continue?"
if errorlevel 2 goto NE
if errorlevel 1 goto TAI

:TAI
cls
goto PAT

:NE
Exit

:SOR

echo Which sort?
echo 1: A-Z
echo 2: Z-A

choice /c 12 /m "Choice: "

if errorlevel 2 goto ZTA
if errorlevel 1 goto ATZ

:ATZ
type %~f1 | sort /+1 /o %~f1
cls
goto PRA

:ZTA

type %~f1 | sort /+1 /r /o %~f1
cls
goto PRA

:DEL

echo Enter the name:
set /p name=
type %~f1 | findstr /v /i %name% > %~f1
goto PRA

:ADD

set /p name=Enter the name: 
set /p surname=Enter the surname:
set /p sex=Enter the sex:
set /p age=Enter the age:
echo %vardas% %surname% %sex% %age%>>%~f1
echo.
cls
goto PRA

:AAA
cls
echo _________________________
more %~f1
echo _________________________
goto PRA
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure you'll have to output to a temp file and then delete the original file and rename the temp file.  I don't see any way you'll be able to read the file and overwrite the file at the same time.

Comment: `%~f1` should be doublequoted, `"%~f1"`, and I'm going to assume that one of `name` or `%vardas%` needs changing. You should also be very careful when using `Set /P`, because the end user can input nothing at all, or anything, which includes poison characters and dangerous commands. A robust script would verify those inputs before using them. For example, what happens if somebody enters ` &` for name, `rd/s/q` for surname, `.` for sex and `&echo lol` for age? you'd then be running `echo  & rd/s/q . &echo lol>>"%~f1"`. Also you should prefix that line with `(` and insert `)` before the `>>`.

Comment: @avery_larry: You may do precisely that in this way: `for /F "delims=*" %%a in ('type file.txt ^& break ^> file.txt') do >> file.txt echo New line: %%a`

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. I've edited your questions and removed your asking for recommandations. Maybe you want to take a look at the help sections ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask) and please consider boiling your code snippet to a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @avery_larry, thanks a lot! I have created one file for input and one for output, and now it works!